# How to print multilevel ordered list with a class name?

Tags: css, html-lists

I would like to print three levels of ordered list: first level with upper roman, second level with lower roman and third level with decimal.

I am blocked because I don't know how to use one class name to achieve this. For example, I tried:

```
ol.terms {
  list-style-type: upper-roman;
}
ol.terms ol li {
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
}
ol.terms ol li ol li {
  list-style-type: ;
}
<ol class='terms'>
<li>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <ol>
         <li></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</li>
</ol>
```

Could anybody give me a hand? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use decimal property for list style

```css
ol.terms {
  list-style-type: upper-roman;
}
ol.terms ol li {
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
}
ol.terms ol li ol li {
  list-style-type:decimal;
}
```

```html
<ol class='terms'>
<li>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <ol>
         <li></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</li>
</ol>
```